# Xpath to pull Max value when there are multiple Matches

Tags: xml, xpath, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am creating a hive external table from xml.  I want to pull the value of an element where the Timestamp is maximum. How do i write this in the Create Table Statement ?

My XML :

```
 <Parent>
    <Child>
        <Purchase value ="100" id ="350" timestamp="2016-10-08T14:22:31.0000000">
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <Purchase value ="110" id ="350" timestamp="2016-10-08T14:22:32.0000000">
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <Purchase value ="105" id ="350" timestamp="2016-10-09T14:22:32.0000000">
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <Purchase value ="75" id ="350" timestamp="2016-10-10T14:22:32.0000000">
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

The below query gives me all the 4 prices. But I want only the price for the most recent TimeStamp ? How to do in Hive?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Recommended_StagingTable (

 ItemPrice INT
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  "column.xpath.id" ="/Parent/Child/Purchase[@id='350']/@value"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add purchase_timestamp column to the Recommended_StagingTable  then use sql row_number analytic funtion to find the latest by timestamp:

```
select ItemPrice 
  from 
      (
      select 
            ItemPrice ,
            purchase_timestamp,
            row_number() over(order by purchase_timestamp desc ) rn
                              --add partition by if necessary 
        from Recommended_StagingTable
      )s
 where rn = 1; --the latest by timestamp
```